# Python rdflib and SPARQL BIND support

Tags: python, bind, sparql, rdflib

I am trying various SPARQL queries with BIND() function and neither seem to work with rdflib 4.0.

Each time I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1045, in query
    query_object, initBindings, initNs, **kwargs))
  File "~/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdfextras/sparql/processor.py", line 49, in query
    loadContexts=loadContexts)
  File "~/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdfextras/sparql/algebra.py", line 406, in TopEvaluate
    assert isinstance(expr,AlgebraExpression), repr(expr)
```

**edit** Here's the query:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?aspectA ?predicateURI ?aspectLabel. } 
WHERE { ?aspectA aspects:A0060 ?aspectType; 
                 aspects:A0101 ?aspectLabel. 
        BIND ( IRI( CONCAT("some.uri/raw/aspects#A";, ?aspectType) ) AS ?predicateURI ). 
}
```

Any hints on what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you show the actual query you're trying?

Comment: Here it is: 

  CONSTRUCT  
  {
    ?aspectA ?predicateURI ?aspectLabel.             
  }
  WHERE
  {
    ?aspectA aspects:A0060 ?aspectType;
             aspects:A0101 ?aspectLabel.
    BIND ( IRI( CONCAT("http://some.uri/raw/aspects#A", ?aspectType) ) AS ?predicateURI ).
  }

Comment: Thanks. It's better to put code examples and queries into the actual question though, rather than posting them as comments: in the actual question, they can be  formatted properly and are thus a lot easier to read. I've taken care of it for you this time around.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that. I've tried all known ways to format this query and could not figure how to do it properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem came from.
I started the project with some old rdflib which required rdfextras. They I upgraded rdflib to 4.0 (and eventually to 4.2-dev) where rdfextras are no longer necessary. Actually, registering them was causing that problem. Once I uninstalled rdfextras and removed plugin.register entries referencing them everything started to run smoothly.